# ALSA - Get current audio peak level

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am currently looking for the simplest solution to get in terminal current peak value that is being played through Raspberry Pi one of the audio outputs.

I have seen that there are solutions that are to complex. I just need to parse the value from 0 - 100, or similiar. I don't need any visual representation or anything, just the current peak level.

Have any of you any stumbled across any solution that I could simply reuse?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way around to make it work. I have used `ffplay` based on `ffmpeg`:

```
ffplay -i vocal.mp3  -nodisp -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level
```